# Is there an alternative for ind.oneway.second from the rpsych package in R? Can't seem to get that package working

Tags: anova

I'm looking for a way to run a one-way anova in R using only summary data (mean, sd, n).  Everything online says to use ind.oneway.second from the rpsychi package, so I've been trying to make it work.

When I try to install rpsychi I get the following warning:
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘rpsychi’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

I have tried installing an older version using:
library(remotes)
install_version("rpsychi", "0.7")

This seems to do something, but then when I try to load the rpsychi library it gives an error saying there is no such package.

I am using R version 4.1.2. Am I just missing something? Should I be able to get this package going? Alternatively, is there another package that does something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
install.packages("gtools")
```

BEFORE executing:

```
library(remotes) 
install_version("rpsychi", "0.8")     # ?
```

For me under R 4.2.1 it installs perfectly this way and can be loaded as usual with library(rpsychi)